# Plotly: Sort multicategory bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have some problems sorting  a multicategorial chart.

Some example code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [
    [0, "Born", 4, "Rhino"],  # commenting this line will also reverse sub category sorting
    [0, "Died", -1, "Rhino"],
    [1, "Born", 4, "Lion"],
    [1, "Died", -1, "Lion"],
    [2, "Born", 12, "Rhino"],
    [2, "Died", -5, "Lion"],
]
z_data = list(zip(*data))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "tick": z_data[0],
    "category": z_data[1],
    "value": z_data[2],
    "type": z_data[3],
})
df = df.sort_values(by=['tick', 'category', 'value', 'type'])
print(df)
fig = go.Figure()
for t in df.type.unique():
    plot_df = df[df.type == t]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=[plot_df.tick, plot_df.category],
        y=abs(plot_df.value),
        name=t,
    ))
fig.update_layout({
    'barmode': 'stack',
    'xaxis': {
        'title_text': "Tick",
        'tickangle': -90,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title_text': "Value",
    },
})
fig.write_html(str("./diagram.html"))
```

[image: uncommented]
[image: commented]

As you can see the tick 2 is before tick 1. This happens because the 'Rhino' is the first in type list, which will create the tick 0 and 2. The lion bars are added after with tick 1.
But how can i sort the bars properly now?

PS. `'barmode': 'stack'` is on purpose. Even if it is not used in this test example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to fix the tick but not the born/died order. I'm planning to plot row by row so I need to  play with showlegend

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = [
    [0, "Born", 4, "Rhino"],  # commenting this line will also reverse sub category sorting
    [0, "Died", -1, "Rhino"],
    [1, "Born", 4, "Lion"],
    [1, "Died", -1, "Lion"],
    [2, "Born", 12, "Rhino"],
    [2, "Died", -5, "Lion"],
]
# you don't really need to zip here
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["tick", "category", "value", "type"])
df["value"] = df["value"].abs()
```

## Set color

In case you have more types there are answer here that can help you. Check [doc](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express)

```py
color_diz = {"Rhino": "blue", "Lion": "red"}
df["color"] = df["type"].map(color_diz)
```

## Show Legend

Here I want to show the legend for the first occurrence of every type

```py
grp = df.groupby("type")\
        .apply(lambda x: x.index.min())\
        .reset_index(name="idx")

df = pd.merge(df, grp, on=["type"], how="left")

df["showlegend"] = df.index == df["idx"]
```

## Data to plot

```py
print(df)
```

```
   tick category  value   type color  idx  showlegend
0     0     Born      4  Rhino  blue    0        True
1     0     Died      1  Rhino  blue    0       False
2     1     Born      4   Lion   red    2        True
3     1     Died      1   Lion   red    2       False
4     2     Born     12  Rhino  blue    0       False
5     2     Died      5   Lion   red    2       False
```

## Plot

```py
fig = go.Figure()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=[[row["tick"]], [row["category"]]],
               y=[row["value"]],
               name=row["type"],
               marker_color=row["color"],
               showlegend=row["showlegend"],
               legendgroup=row["type"] # Fix legend
               ))
    
fig.update_layout({
    'barmode': 'stack',
    'xaxis': {
        'title_text': "Tick",
        'tickangle': -90,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title_text': "Value",
    },
})
fig.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you have more `type` you could use the following trick.

First I  generate different types

```py
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"type":np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 100)})
```

Then I pick a color sequence from [doc](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express) and put them on a dictionary

```py
color_dict = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)}
```

Then I put the unique `type` on a dataframe

```py
df_col = pd.DataFrame({"type": df["type"].unique()})
```

and I assign each of them a color according to its index

```py
df_col["color"] = (df_col.index%len(color_dict)).map(color_dict)
```

Finally I merge to the original df

```py
df = pd.merge(df, df_col, on=["type"], how="left")
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically apply colors to the same category if you have much more categories?

Comment: Also this do not solves the problem with the legend at all, because if you want to hide all Lions, the shown legend item is only associated with one bar.

Comment: @IceflowerS I fixed the legend using `legendgroup`. See the plot section.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I used this for the color: 
```python
df_col = pd.DataFrame({
        "type": df["type"].unique(),
        "color": seaborn.color_palette("bright", len(df["type"].unique())).as_hex(),
    })
```